# What's best practice for a series of regex matches?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have some category-identification logic which operates via a series of regex matches against various fields in a row. For example, it might look something like this:

```py
patterns = {
  'pattern1': re.compile(r'(AIRWAY.*CLEAR)'),
  'pattern2': re.compile(r'(OTHERPATTERN)')
}

cat_id = 9999

if unit_cost >= 23000 and patterns['pattern1'].search(physician_comment):
  cat_id = 5320

if unit_cost >= 50000 and patterns['pattern1'].search(physician_comment):
  cat_id = 5321

if patterns['pattern2'].search(charge_code) and cat_id == 9999:
  cat_id = 2
```

There are about 300 `if` statements and at the end we have a `cat_id` which we apply to the row. We want to move this into PySpark, but it seems to be hanging. Here's what we're trying to do:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

patterns = {
  'pattern1a': r'(AIRWAY.*CLEAR)',
  'pattern1b': r'(AIRWAY.*EMPTY)',
  'pattern2': r'(OTHERPATTERN)'
}

aci = 'CategoryId'

def categorize(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
  df = df.withColumn(
    aci,
    F.when(
      F.col(charge_code_name).rlike(patterns['pattern1a']) |
      F.col(charge_code_name).rlike(patterns['pattern1b']),
    1010).otherwise(F.col(aci)))

  df = df.withColumn(
    aci,
    F.when(
      (F.col(unit_cost) >= 23000) &
      (F.col(physician_comment).rlike(patterns['pattern2'])),
    1020).otherwise(F.col(aci)))

  [...]

  return df
```

Instead of 300 `if` statements, we'll have 300 `df = df.withColumn(aci, F.when(...).otherwise(F.col(aci)))` statements - but we've migrated the first ~30 of these over to PySpark, and upon testing, Spark does not seem to like it, and hangs after the initial data load.

Is this a bad pattern for some reason? Are we doing something wrong? What's the right way to implement this pattern of sequential regex matches against a row in PySpark?

**UPDATE**

We ended up using a different pattern which seems to be working well. I still don't know why the original approach isn't good, but here's what we went with -- it ends up generating a chained list of F.when([condition], [val]).otherwise(F.when([condition2], [val2]).otherwise(...))).

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

patterns = {
  'pattern1': r'(AIRWAY.*CLEAR)',
  'pattern2': r'(OTHERPATTERN)'
}

catid_title = 'CategoryId'
unitcost_title = 'UnitCost'
chargecode_title = 'ChargeCode'
cat_id = F.col(catid_title)
unit_cost = F.when(F.col(col_unitcost).isNotNull(), 
    F.col(col_unitcost)).otherwise(0)
charge_code = F.col(chargecode_title)

rules = []

rules.append(F.when(
    (unit_cost >= 23000) & (physician_comment.rlike(patterns["pattern1"])), 5320))

rules.append(F.when(
    (unit_cost >= 50000) & (physician_comment.rlike(patterns['pattern1'])), 5321))

rules.append(F.when((cat_id == 9999) & charge_code.rlike(patterns['pattern2']), 2))

# Apply rules in reverse order.
rules[0] = rules[0].otherwise(F.col(aci))
for i in range(1, len(rules)):
  rules[i] = rules[i].otherwise(rules[i - 1])

df = df.withColumn(cat_id, rules[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could merge several `withColumn` into one. From your example, this:

```py
def categorize(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
  df = df.withColumn(
    aci,
    F.when(
      F.col(charge_code_name).rlike(patterns['pattern1a']) |
      F.col(charge_code_name).rlike(patterns['pattern1b']),
    1010).otherwise(F.col(aci)))

  df = df.withColumn(
    aci,
    F.when(
      (F.col(unit_cost) >= 23000) &
      (F.col(physician_comment).rlike(patterns['pattern2'])),
    1020).otherwise(F.col(aci)))
```

can be turned into this:

```py
def categorize(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
  df = df.withColumn(
    aci,
    F.when(
      F.col(charge_code_name).rlike(patterns['pattern1a']) |
      F.col(charge_code_name).rlike(patterns['pattern1b']),
    1010)
    .when(
      (F.col(unit_cost) >= 23000) &
      (F.col(physician_comment).rlike(patterns['pattern2'])),
    1020)
    .otherwise(F.col(aci)))
```

Comment: How can we update this approach in a scenerio where if two rules are satisfied, we want to give preference to the latter rule? In the current approach, it will never go to the next rule if the former rule is satisfied.  Is there a way to implement it as a series of if statements without the else's?

Comment: Every case is different, you will need to review all the rules and create the series of ifs depending on your case. The example you gave seems simple, but in the reality it's probably not. You give preference by moving the condition to the front. But as said, you will have to carefully review your logic.